# Convert html in column cells to text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, html

I have a column in Excel of descriptions. These descriptions are in HTML format, and need to have that HTML converted into plain text, by stripping out all the HTML tags.

I don't know my way around Excel, so the alternative I have investigated would be to use fgetcsv php function and html2text, and then export as Excel.

Probably this may be a long-winded solution if there is some setting/VBA code on Excel that would do the trick.

Any help very welcome.

Example of HTML data in Excel:

```
<p> <strong><span style="font-size: 16px"><u>Socket & See LTKIT10 Lamp Test Adaptor Kit</u></span></strong> </p> <p> This fantastic product from Socket & See is ideal for Electricians testing light fittings. </p> <p> The Socket & See LTKIT10 is five adaptors that allow for easy connection and testing at light fittings: </p> <p> LTBC 02, LTES 04, LTMBC 06, LTMES 08, LTGU 10 </p> <p> Presented with 2 x 120cm, 4mm test leads in a protective carry pouch. </p> <br/> 
<p> <strong>Features of Socket & See LTKIT10:</strong> </p> <ul> <li>Allows easy, safe connection to light fittings </li> <li>The fastest way to check insulation/continuity/loop/polarity </li> <li>High quality low ohn 4mm connectors </li> <li>Safer and saves time: leave the light fitting in place </li> <li>Easier/better connection allows hands-free </li> <li>No broken connections </li> <li>Great for use in awkward/high situations </li> <li>No damage to fittings</li></ul> <br/> <p> <strong>What's included:</strong> </p> 
<p> Bayonet Fitting, GU10, Small Edison Screw, Small Bayonet Fitting, Edison Screw Fitting, 2 x 120cm, 4mm Test Leads, Protective Carrier Pouch<br /> </p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is unclear what you are asking. When you say *"converted into just text"*, do you mean you want the remove HTML tags? Excel is not an HTML editor, so there are no special functions to remove tags. Have you tried `Find & Replace`?

Comment: Or, to further CharlieRB, see http://www.digocodigo.com/2012/03/code-to-strip-html-tags-in-notepad-and.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer CharileRB, What I mean with "converted to just text" is to have the tags striped and also text formated.

Comment: If you have the HTML formatted page you can import the data into excel using  the “From Web” menu under Data > Get External Data group. The new Web Query Dialog pop up opens – type the  URL and select import.
Click the Yellow Arrows next to the tables that you would like to bring into Excel as text and Import.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all tags and text, paste in a text file, change the extension file from txt to html, open with the browser, copy the contents from web page and paste in excel.

Comment: Not a practical solution is someone has hundreds or even thousands of rows of data.